# How to cast object to EntitySet with variable generic

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, linq-to-sql, casting

I have a variable (type: `object`) called o. I also have a variable (type: `Type`) called t. I know that o is an `EntitySet` with the type of t with a single entry in it.

I need to get the first element in the EntitySet so that I can use reflection on it to get it's propertys. Have tried a couple of approaches to getting the first element, but none have worked.

1. Cast o to EntitySet - sounds good but dont know how to do this with t being a variable that can change
2. Cast o to dynamic
3. Cast o to EntitySet - The intention is that then I can use the methods of EntitySet and get first object but it throws an exception

Have:

```
Type t;    
object o; // we know it's EntitySet<t>
```

I need

```
t firstElement = o[0];
```

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more context than this.  It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish and why.

Comment: @DavidL What was unclear? I've reread and am unsure what is unclear.

Comment: Did you try casting the object to IList?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast it to a `IEnumerable<object>` since `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. IList wont work.

```
Type t;    
object o;
var objList = (IEnumerable<object>)o;
var firstObject = objList.First();
//Do your reflection magic with firstObject
```

Comment: I dont see a problem with the non generic IList here.

Comment: You are correct. IList will work as well. IList<object> will not work.